# Same symbol appears in Matplotlib legends

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am studying machine learning course in couseera. I have made a plot for a data and trying to make a legend. I referred online and used this format

```
plt.figure(1)
plt.title('input data plot')
plt.xlabel('Exam 1 marks')
plt.ylabel('Exam 2 marks')
plt.plot(X[temp0,0],X[temp0,1],'or')
plt.plot(X[temp1,0],X[temp1,1],'xb')
plt.plot(x_boundary,y_boundary,'-g')
plt.legend(['Not admitted','Admitted','Decision Boundary'],numpoints=1)
plt.show()
```

The output is  with the same symbol for all types [image: same legend]

Then I used another format given below

```
plt.figure(1)
plt.title('input data plot')
plt.xlabel('Exam 1 marks')
plt.ylabel('Exam 2 marks')
plt.plot(X[temp0,0],X[temp0,1],'or',label='Not admitted')
plt.plot(X[temp1,0],X[temp1,1],'xb',label='Admitted')
plt.plot(x_boundary,y_boundary,'-g',label='Decision Boundary')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

It resulted with legend for all the data[image: many legends]

Could anyone help me in fixing this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you create a [mcve]?

Comment: What is the format of your data? Can you tell me what value `len(X[temp0,0])` has?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say for sure without further information, but I strongly suspect your problem is with your data. If your array of values is contained within another array you will get the behaviour you see in the second example.

Look at this example to see the difference:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

# Note the extra array brackets. This is not good.
X = [[random.randint(0,10) for i in range(0,5)]]
Y = [[random.randint(0,10) for i in range(0,5)]]

X1 = [random.randint(0,10)for i in range(0,5)]
Y1 = [random.randint(0,10)for i in range(0,5)]

plt.plot(X,Y,'or',label='Double Array')
plt.plot(X1,Y1,'xb',label='Single Array')

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: Example of double array's messing up legends]

Comment: This is the correct answer – namely: use `plt.plot(..., label='...')` instead of specifying the labels in the `.legend()` call.